# Anaconda - Install blpapi in environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, bloomberg

I have py2.7 as my original Anaconda install, and have installed py3.4 in an environment named `py3`.

I cannot seem to be able to install `blpapi`, the Bloomberg API library, in the `py3` environment.

Once I `activate py3`, `conda install blpapi` cannot find the package, whereas `pip install blpapi` tells me that:

```
Requirement already satisfied: blpapi in C:\users\pythonic\programs\anaconda\lib\site-packages
```

Because it finds the package installed for python 2.7

If I try to install via the executable from [here](https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/) it tells me that it cannot find python 3.4 in the registry.

How do I install this package?

**Edit**

Apparently the DSM channel does not have the py3.5 version anymore but this channel does

https://anaconda.org/macinv/blpapi/files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution would be creating a Python 3.5 environment:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
```

activating it:

```
activate py35
```

and installing `blpapi` form the channel `dsm`:

```
conda install -c dsm blpapi
```

The channel [dsm](https://anaconda.org/dsm/blpapi) is an [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) channel. It provides these [files](https://anaconda.org/dsm/blpapi/files):

```
win-64/blpapi-3.9.0-py35_0.tar.bz2  
win-64/blpapi-3.5.5-py27_0.tar.bz2  
linux-64/blpapi-3.5.5-py27_0.tar.bz2
```

This means `blpapi` is available for Windows for Python 2.7 and 3.5 but not for 3.4.

To find a package, enter the package name in the [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) search window (top of page).

Comment: Thanks Mike. For my understanding, what is the DSM channel and why does it not work for py3.4? Trying the solution as we speak. Edit: works like a charm, thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with more explanation.

Comment: Saw that thanks, I am trying to figure out how to browse conda channels - dsm did not emerge from a quick "conda channel blpapi" search

Comment: The dsm channel has been updated, currently py36 and py27 are supported. Check https://anaconda.org/dsm/blpapi/files for most current builds

Comment: Yes I think I was commenting in reference to the Linux builds changing, I should have been more explicit. The was related to someone referring to this question with issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725483/anaconda-install-blpapi-in-environment

Comment: For Python 3.5.4, this worked for me: https://anaconda.org/macinv/blpapi

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Mike Müller's answer above, I thought I would add a section on the `anaconda search` utility for finding packages hosted on https://anaconda.org/.

```
$ anaconda search blpapi
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Packages:
     Name                      |  Version | Package Types   | Platforms       | Builds    
     ------------------------- |   ------ | --------------- | --------------- | ----------
     conda-forge/blpapi        |    3.9.2 | conda           | linux-64, win-64, osx-64 | py27h2d50403_0, py36he980bc4_0, py36h2d50403_0, py27hdc96acc_0
                                      : Python SDK for Bloomberg BLPAPI (<=3.9)
     dsm/blpapi                |    3.9.0 | conda           | linux-64, win-64 | py36_0, py27_0
     josh/blpapi               |    3.5.5 | conda           | linux-64        | py27_0    
     macinv/blpapi             |    3.9.0 | conda           | linux-64, win-64 | py36_0, py27_0, py35_0, py34_0
     mbonix/blpapi             |    3.9.0 | conda           | win-64          | py36_0    
                                      : Bloomberg's Open Market Data Initiative is part of the company's ongoing effort to foster open solutions for the financial services industry.
     p-vg/blpapi               |    3.9.2 | conda           | linux-64, win-64 | py36h6538335_0, py27hc56fc5f_0, py36hf484d3e_0, py27hf484d3e_0
                                      : interface for Bloomberg API services using the Python programming language
Found 6 packages
```

Depending on the version of `python` and `platform` you are interested in, there are a varierty of options available.

Comment: For python 3.8, you could use conda-forge channel. It works for me.