# Conda install BLPAPI

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, blpapi

I followed the answer in:

[Anaconda - Install blpapi in environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725483/anaconda-install-blpapi-in-environment)

but could not comment because I don't reputation high enough. When I use `conda install -c dsm/blpapi` I get the following:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: ....


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - blpapi
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

This is using a virtual environment with Python 3.5 installed. Any thoughts on why this works for `Pythonic` but not me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built package for `python=3.5`. If you look under the files section of the [repo](https://anaconda.org/dsm/blpapi/files) in the dsm channel you will see

```
linux-64/blpapi-3.9.0-py36_0.tar.bz2
win-64/blpapi-3.9.0-py27_0.tar.bz2
win-64/blpapi-3.5.5-py27_0.tar.bz2
linux-64/blpapi-3.5.5-py27_0.tar.bz2
```

Switching to Python 3.6 should get this to work.

Comment: Upgrading to 3.6 didn't work for me, because I am on windows. Here's another repo with the latest blpapi 3.9.2 and works with python 3.6 and 2.7 both linux and windows. https://anaconda.org/p-vg/blpapi/files

Answer (score 2):

did you try ? :

```
conda update --all
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
activate py35
conda install -c dsm blpapi=3.9.0
```

you can also download from :

https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/

and put it in the repository of python 3.5 library

Comment: yes I created a new python environment and tried my current one as well; same error. I will try putting it in the blapi in the repository

Comment: could you provide some further details about how to add to the repository of the python library?

Comment: are you on windows, linux or mac ?

Comment: I don't know if there is specificity on windows, I have always been using linux, but if you download the package from blooberglabs website, then you'll have a readme file with detail about how to install (without using conda)

Comment: I see if you use the self-extracting file from bloomberg it throws off a similar error, suggesting it only works with Python 3.4. I had thought there was a way around this but perhaps i should just downgrade to 3.4

Comment: I  don't know more about that... sorry but I have found this post that maybe help : https://medium.com/@ashishsingal1/installing-bloomberg-api-on-windows-anaconda-python-3-5-fa67e820c3a2

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted, Bloomberg put the blpapi on conda-forge, 
Which has more versions of the blpapi and python supported.

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/blpapi