# Need help in installing blpapi and configuring Python Interpreter

Tags: python, pip, conda, blpapi

I am using Python 3.5 64 bit and Windows Machine. Normally i install packages using pip installer.

For blpapi library(bloomberg API), i used the steps mentioned in answer from following question [Anaconda - Install blpapi in environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725483/anaconda-install-blpapi-in-environment#)

Steps I followed:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
activate py35
conda install -c macinv blpapi
```

This worked fine. But it has created a separate Python Environment and Interpreter

C:\Users\bl00mb3rg\Miniconda3\envs\py35

Already i have another python interpreter which was created while intalling python 3.5 64 bit.

Which Interpreter i have to use while configuring python IDE. If i select Conda python Env, i am not able to use libraries such as 'pdblp' which i installed using pip

How to make Conda install libraries in existing python instead of creating new Environment.

Comment: Try `conda install -c mbonix blpapi` using _Anaconda prompt_

Comment: Thanks! This works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install using *Anaconda Prompt*

`conda install -c mbonix blpapi`

Comment: Then i used pip to install other libraries using Anaconda prompt. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://anaconda.org/p-vg/blpapi/files

1. This is the latest version of blpapi 3.9.2
2. It has both packages for python 3.6 and 2.7
3. Both windows and linux

`conda install -c p-vg blpapi`

Answer (score 1):

This is tangential to the question, but you do not *have* to use conda; per [Bloomberg's API Library page](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/), you can run:

```
python -m pip install --index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi
```

from within your existing environment.